# Travelling (verb) - to (preposition)

Tags: prepositions, verbs

1. He is travelling the mountains.
2. He is travelling to the mountains.

These two sentences look similar to me but I am still puzzled between them. Are they similar?

Does my first sentence imply that he is travelling to many mountains around the country/cities/towns, he has come with an objective to travel the mountains?

Does my second sentence imply that he is travelling in the direction of mountains, he is gonna reach there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"I travelled the highways of that country for years"  means that I spent years travelling along the roads. i.e. my journey was along those roads.

"He is travelling the mountains" means that currently he is in the act of travelling through, across, or over the mountains.

"I travelled to the mountains" means that my journey began somewhere else, and ended once I got to the mountains.

"He is travelling to the mountains" means that currently he is in the act of travelling towards the mountains.  He has not reached them yet.  (And we don't yet know if he ever will reach them. Only time will tell).

Answer (score 0):

The first sentence describes that the traveler has reached the 'mountains' (the hill station, rather), is currently located at the hill station (and is probably walking on top of the mountains)

The second one describes that the traveler has not yet reached her destination (the hill station) and is on her way (probably travelling through the roads and yet to reach the place where the mountains are located)